# Determine if Python variable is an instance of a built-in type

Tags: python, variables, instance

I need to determine if a given Python variable is an instance of native type: `str`, `int`, `float`, `bool`, `list`, `dict` and so on. Is there elegant way to doing it?

Or is this the only way:

```
if myvar in (str, int, float, bool):
    # do something
```

Comment: What do you mean by "native" type?  Do you mean builtin?  Why do you need to know this?  Python isn't C++ or Java, so there's no distinction between "simple" or "native" types.  What are  you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I guess I mean "builtin" types.

I need such representation of an object, that I could use it in JSON serialization. simplejson "handles" only such types. In other cases (when object are instances of "homemade" classes) i need to make dict objects.

Comment: You know that simplejson has something called "object decoding" and "object encoding"?

Comment: Yes, But as I understood this - I should write such decoder for each kind of class I want to serialize. I don't want to do it.

Comment: @Aleksandr Motsjonov: Please update your question to specifically say that you're interested in types that simplejson handles by default.

Comment: @Aleksandr Motsjonov: Even when you need one decoder per type, it's irrelevant if that type is builtin or not. I updated my answer to reflect your actual problem.

Comment: you should really look at S.Lott's answer 'cause it's better than the one you picked... I added some code to show how it would actually be used, but you really shouldn't care if something is a builtin or not, instead you should see if what you are trying to do is supported, and otherwise try something else

Comment: "How do I determine whether the value is **of a type that `simplejson` can serialize without additional work**?" is a **completely different question** that has **nothing to do with** whether the type is "native" or "builtin" or anything else like that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to collect the types in a list of tuple called `primitiveTypes` and:

```
if isinstance(myvar, primitiveTypes): ...
```

The [`types` module](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html) contains collections of all important types which can help to build the list/tuple.

[Works since Python 2.2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Comment: using types from 'types' is no different than using the more straightforward names (int, str, float, ...) directly!

Comment: Yes, that's how types works. But it makes your intention more clean and if you use the predefined sets (StringTypes), you get additional portability between Python versions.

Comment: It's also slightly faster ... ;)

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best approach. Basically you import types from the `types` modules and check against them, but the docs discourages this way since python 2.2 on. Accordingly to the docs using `isinstance` is preferred. [The 2nd code example shows a simple case](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html).

Comment: @Guandalino: Thanks, improved my answer.

Comment: Note that the `types` module does *not* really provide a complete list of types. For example there's no `int` there. However there's the `buildins` module that provides most built-ins, so one can do `builtin_types = tuple(getattr(builtins, t) for t in dir(builtins) if isinstance(getattr(builtins, t), type))` and then use `isinstance(value, builtin_types)`.

Comment: "..dict and so on.": Suddenly isinstance(NamedTuple, tuple) == true. Class name/builtins should be also checked.

Comment: `isinstance` is true for subclasses of builtin types, whereas `type(value) in (bool, str, int, float, tuple, list, dict)` is true only for instances of the builtin types. This difference is pointed out in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392016/1959808

Answer (score 33):

This is an old question but it seems none of the answers actually answer the specific question: "(How-to) Determine if Python variable is an instance of a built-in type". Note that it's not "[...] of a **specific/given** built-in type" but of **a**.

The proper way to *determine if a given object is an instance of a buil-in type/class* is to check if the type of the object happens to be defined in the module `__builtin__`.

```
def is_builtin_class_instance(obj):
    return obj.__class__.__module__ == '__builtin__'
```

Warning: if `obj` is a class and not an instance, no matter if that class is built-in or not, True will be returned since a class is also an object, an instance of `type` (i.e. `AnyClass.__class__` is `type`).

Comment: In Python3 the module is called `__builtins__`.

Comment: in Python 3.7 the module is called `builtins`

Comment: @glarrain how would you modify this to handle the general case you mention in which `obj` is a class not an instance?

Comment: @jtlz2 you can store the name in a variable and compare it with that variable, like ```builtin_module_name=dict().__class__.__module__```

Answer (score 12):

Not that I know why you would want to do it, as there isn't any "simple" types in Python, it's all objects. But this works:

```
type(theobject).__name__ in dir(__builtins__)
```

But explicitly listing the types is probably better as it's clearer. Or even better: Changing the application so you don't need to know the difference.

Update: The problem that needs solving is how to make a serializer for objects, even those built-in. The best way to do this is not to make a big phat serializer that treats builtins differently, but to look up serializers based on type.

Something like this:

```
def IntSerializer(theint):
    return str(theint)

def StringSerializer(thestring):
    return repr(thestring)

def MyOwnSerializer(value):
    return "whatever"

serializers = {
    int: IntSerializer,
    str: StringSerializer,
    mymodel.myclass: MyOwnSerializer,
}

def serialize(ob):
    try:
        return ob.serialize() #For objects that know they need to be serialized
    except AttributeError:
        # Look up the serializer amongst the serializer based on type.
        # Default to using "repr" (works for most builtins).
        return serializers.get(type(ob), repr)(ob)
```

This way you can easily add new serializers, and the code is easy to maintain and clear, as each type has its own serializer. Notice how the fact that some types are builtin became completely irrelevant. :)

Comment: +1 "Changing the application so you don't need to know the difference." Some (extremely rare) times is necesary to know, but most likely isn't.

Answer (score 7):

You appear to be interested in assuring the simplejson will handle your types.  This is done trivially by

```
try:
    json.dumps( object )
except TypeError:
    print "Can't convert", object
```

Which is more reliable than trying to guess which types your JSON implementation handles.

Comment: this is more pythonic 'cause if the object can be dumped (say perhaps simplejson adds more support) then it will be used first, and then in the except you should call your catchall functionality. +1

Comment: What if the object is a huge dict? wouldn't it be a waist of resources?

Answer (score 2):

What is a "native type" in Python? Please don't base your code on types, use [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Typing).

Comment: Thanks, I will think twice before do it =)

Answer (score 2):

It's 2020, I'm on python 3.7, and none of the existing answers worked for me. What worked instead is the [builtins module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/builtins.html). Here's how:

```py
import builtins
type(your_object).__name__ in dir(builtins)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access all these types by `types` module:

```
`builtin_types = [ i for i in  types.__dict__.values() if isinstance(i, type)]`
```

as a reminder, import module `types` first

```
def isBuiltinTypes(var):
    return type(var) in types.__dict__.values() and not isinstance(var, types.InstanceType)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the best option is:

```
allowed_modules = set(['numpy'])
def isprimitive(value):
  return not hasattr(value, '__dict__') or \
  value.__class__.__module__ in allowed_modules
```

This fix when value is a module and `value.__class__.__module__ == '__builtin__'` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

building off of S.Lott's answer you should have something like this:

```
from simplejson import JSONEncoder

class JSONEncodeAll(JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, obj):
    try:
      return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
    except TypeError:
      ## optionally
      # try:
      #   # you'd have to add this per object, but if an object wants to do something
      #   # special then it can do whatever it wants
      #   return obj.__json__()
      # except AttributeError:
      ##

      # ...do whatever you are doing now...
      # (which should be creating an object simplejson understands)
```

to use:

```
>>> json = JSONEncodeAll()

>>> json.encode(myObject)
# whatever myObject looks like when it passes through your serialization code
```

these calls will use your special class and if simplejson can take care of the object it will. Otherwise your catchall functionality will be triggered, and possibly (depending if you use the optional part) an object can define it's own serialization

Answer (score 0):

The question asks to check for non-class types. These types don't have a `__dict__` member (You could also test for `__repr__` member, instead of checking for `__dict__`)  Other answers mention to check for membership in `types.__dict__.values()`, but some of the types in this list are classes.

```
def isnonclasstype(val):
    return getattr(val,"__dict__", None) != None

a=2
print( isnonclasstype(a) )

a="aaa"
print( isnonclasstype(a) )

a=[1,2,3]
print( isnonclasstype(a) )

a={ "1": 1, "2" : 2 }
print( isnonclasstype(a) )

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = Foo()
print( isnonclasstype(a) )
```

gives me:

```
> python3 t.py
False
False
False
False
True
> python t.py
False
False
False
False
True
```

Comment: numpy arrays don't have __dict__.

Answer (score 0):

I found a weird way as follows:

```
def isBuiltin(obj):
    if type(obj)!=str and 'at 0x' in repr(obj):
        # XXclass at 0x.... or XXobject
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score -1):

Built in type function may be helpful:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
```