# Check if variable is a standard type function in Python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to catch all the std type functions in Python (int, str, xrange, etc).

Basically anything which has a repr that looks like `<type X>` instead of `<class X>`. Here's a full list of all std types in Python 2:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

If I use `isinstance(X, type)` or `type(X) == type`, it also catches all classes too, but I only want to detect type functions (or any names that's assigned to one of them (i.e. `my_int = int`).

The only idea that comes to my mind is checking if `X.__name__` is in `__builtins__` but I'm not sure if that's a clean nor correct solution.

Comment: Could you explain what you're actually trying to achieve, and why?

Comment: You can list them out explicitly ... `isinstance(x, (list, dict, set, unicode, str, ...))` or `x in {list, dict, set, unicode, str, ...}`.  Out of curiosity, _why_ does it matter if something it a builtin type or not?

Comment: I could list them all out since there's a finite number, but I was hoping to avoid that. I'm trying to catch any primitive type function. I don't think it's possible to create more primitive types in Python? So the only ones that will ever exist are builtins. Anything else will be a class.

Comment: This is close to what I need. I think I may have to just list it afterall as you mentioned. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391694/check-if-a-variables-type-is-primitive

Comment: "Basically anything which has a repr that looks like `<type X>` instead of `<class X>`." - that difference completely goes away in Python 3, and it only exists in Python 2 for historical reasons.

Comment: If you explained what you want to use this check for, it would be a lot easier to determine what you actually need to check.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a variable is a class or a builtin type, use [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module.

```
>>> from inspect import isclass
>>> isclass(object)
True
>>> isclass(5)
False
>>> isclass(int)
True
```

Alternatively, try type(). Works both for Python 2.75 and 3.

```
>>> type(int) is type(type)
True
```

I didn't understand what you mean by "std type functions", I think they may be called just types.

Answer (score 0):

What you suggested seems good to me.

```
builtin = dir(__builtins__)
def is_builtin(tested_object):
    return tested_object.__class__.__name__ in builtin
```

Bear in mind, however, that built-in types can be overshadowed.

Update after comment from Rob:

```
def is_builtin(tested_object):
    return tested_object.__class__.__module__ == '__builtin__'
```

Comment: Or `tested_object.__class__.__module__ == '__builtin__'` ?

Comment: Indeed that is better!