# object and __init__ method

Tags: python, object

I am learning Python and I heard all functions are objects. And classes are objects too, if I am not mistaken. Then methods within a class must be objects.

Then I wonder, within `__init__` method, which is an object, are the attributes objects, too? Objects within an object?

There is a phrase 'Everything is an object'. And my impression is that anything that holds a memory space is an object. What I don't quite grasp is to what extent the phrase 'everything is an object' applies. I wonder if it applies even to variables within `__init__` method.

Comment: Yes, the parameters you pass and the attributes you assign are also (references to) objects.

Comment: The answer to pretty much all of your questions is "yes"

Comment: Every thing in the physical world is matter. Same concept.

Comment: Why would the `__init__` method be any different from any other method?

Comment: Then, to be more precise, when you say objects, they are essentially "references to the objects"?

Comment: @Sean: Names are bound to objects, and can be rebound; "references" is problematic for people from a C++ background (they're not C++ references in any meaningful sense). They're largely similar to C++ `shared_ptr`s, where the *pointers* are passed around by value (and automatically reference counted). Assignment assigns the pointer, all other uses call methods on the object being pointed to, implicitly (e.g. `+` invokes `__add__`) or explicitly.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? PS Who says 'everything is an object' means anything? What justification was given where you saw that in an authoritative reference? What did the author of whereever you heard is claim it meant? It's clearly just a mnemonic for something much larger. Find out what 'object' means & what all those other terms mean & ask a question where you are stuck reading an authoritative presentation or in justifying it yourself to us. Right now you're just asking us to rewrite a textbook & to guess at what somebody meant by something informal.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, it's quite similar to Java. Every Python variable hides a pointer to the right location of memory which contains the actual data. There are only four primitive types in Python: integers, floats, booleans and strings; anything else is an ADT.
The keyword *self* is the same of *this* in Java or C++, in other words the self-reference. Using *self*, you can invoke another method inside the class or access to an attribute. Syntax like `self.var = 1` can also creates a new attribute (if it doesn't exist yet) with name "var", type "int" and value 1.

Comment: There aren't *any* primitive types in Python, that's what "everything is an object" really means.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Python has four primitive types: integers, floats, booleans and strings.

Comment: They're still objects, not primitive in any meaningful sense; they have methods, etc. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392976/3001761

Comment: I use this exemple. "a = 2; print(a);
foo(a); print(a); def foo(a):
a=a+1;". This code prints "2 2". Even if technically ints are object, their behaviour is identical to a classical primitive type (Java ints for instance).

Comment: @A.May: You're likely confused because in many ways they *act* like primitives; they're immutable, so even when you do `x = 5`, `y = x`, `y += 1`, `x` remains unchanged (similar actions with a `list` would mutate `x`, because `x` and `y` would remain aliases; `+=` operates in-place only on mutable types). But they're still full-fledged objects, they have the common Python object header, they're heap-allocated, they have methods, etc. You could compare them to Java's *boxed* primitives (e.g. `Integer`, `Boolean`), which is basically what they are.

Comment: That example has an error, foo is used before it's defined. Fixing that it still doesn't illustrate what you claim; you'd get the same behaviour with `a = [2]` and `a = a + [1]`, for example, and lists aren't a type you consider primitive.

Comment: Also Python is strongly *but dynamically* typed; `self.var = 1` doesn't create an attribute with type int, it creates an attribute whose ^current value* has the type int.

Comment: @A.May that works exactly the same with any object, your exaple demonstrates nothing. **There are no primitive types in Python**.

Comment: Primitive types are intended like "passed by value" variable because of their immutability. It was just an easier explanation. A non-primitive type would fail in the previous exemple and it would modify 'a'.

Comment: I've just shown you an example with a list that disproves that. Python doesn't pass e.g. ints in a different way to e.g. lists.

Comment: @A.May no it wouldn't. The evaluation strategy is **exactly the same** for **all types** in Python. Again, try `def foo(x): x = x + [1]; y = []; foo(y); print(y)` the difference is that *int objects lack any mutator methods*, i.e., they are immutable, but if you really want to, you can use `ctypes` to modify the object (relying on implementation details) and you will see that `int` objects are really objects, and they are passed to functions **exactly** like any other object Python, unlike Java, is purely object oriented in this regard, there *are no non-object types*

Comment: I've just learned a new thing. I was absolutely sure about the analogy with Java. Sorry guys.