# How to check if a variable is instance of any class

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out the best and/or most elegant way to check if a variable is instance of any class except built-in types like `int`, `float`, `tuple`, `dict`, `list`, etc., that is why I cannot do something like:

```
>>> hasattr(some_var, '__class__')
```

Currently, what I am doing is the following:

```
>>> class DummyClass(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> my_var = DummyClass()
>>> 'class' in str(type(my_var))
True
>>> 'class' in str(type([]))
False
>>> 'class' in str(type(3.43))
False
```

Because it works with built-in types (returns `False`), but I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1322068/217324 (shows how to list the built-in types w/o hardcoding)

Comment: What about classes which extend `dict`?

Comment: @Aaron that's a good one, I didn't even think about it