Distinguish native type from user type
I want to be able to distinguish some native class like _functools.partial (code, code) from some user-class like:
class MyClass:
    pass

I want to test this from within Python (so not using the CPython API or so). But it's ok if this only works with CPython. It should work for CPython >=3.6.
How?
More specifically, I want to distinguish objects where its __dict__/__slots__ will not give me all the object attributes. This is usually the case for native types such as _functools.partial  where the func, args, keywords are not in __dict__ (and __slots__ does not exist).
I think basically I want to check if the type defines some custom Py_tp_members (but not derived from __slots__ (see)).

Some background / ideas which might be helpful to get to an answer:

functools.partial.__dict__ is usually empty or None.
functools.partial.__slots__ only exists if Python uses the pure Python implementation, which is usually not the case.
functools.partial.__getstate__() exists since Python >=3.11 and will return __dict__ (and maybe __slots__), so in case of the native partial, it will be empty or None. (Not sure if this is really correct. See CPython issue #125094.)
functools.partial.__dir__(functools.partial) also does not cover func and co? However, dir(functools.partial) does? Side question: What is the builtin dir doing differently? Where is the exact code of the builtin dir which covers this case? I assume it iterates through the Py_tp_members, maybe also Py_tp_methods?
I initially thought that maybe __dictoffset__ gives me some hint, but that turned out to be wrong.
The builtin dir could probably be used in any case. The inspect.getmembers (or also inspect.getmembers_static) might tell me what I need to know.


Why do I need that?
We need to define our own custom hash (not __hash__) for any type of object, in a stable way (that the hash does not change across Python versions), and in a meaningful way (that the hash contains all relevant state). So far, we iterate over __getstate__(), or __dict__/__slots__, which works fine for most cases, except now for functools.partial, and likely for other native types. So the idea was, add a check if we have a native type, and if so, fallback to using dir, as that seems to work fine even in those cases.
See Sisyphus issue #207 and Sisyphus get_object_state and Sisyphus sis_hash_helper.

How far do you want to cast the "builtin" net…? Some builtins are implemented in C, while others are just libraries written in Python that happen to come in the default installation. So there's no technical difference to user defined classes. You'd either need to look at the path of the defining file, or have a list of all possible types you consider "built in". — What difference does it make for you anyway?

Sorry, "builtin" was the wrong term. I meant specifically types defined by native C code. Or more generally, classes where __dict__/__slots__ would not cover all attribs.

Ditto what @deceze said, What problem would it enable you to solve if you could distinguish the types, and why do you think you cannot solve it in some other way?

@SolomonSlow I extended the question to explain that. But I feel like the question is really independent of this background, and even if you now tell me that there are much better solutions, where I don't need to know the answer for this question, I still would be curious about the answer to exactly this question.

By hash you mean builtin hash? It might be different even across the same python but within different interpreter instances.

@Sergius No not the builtin hash. Some custom own hash which is stable.

That's fair, but it's a common occurrence on this site that a person asking about one problem actually is going down the wrong path to solve some other problem that they have not mentioned. https://xyproblem.info/ I just wanted to make sure that it wasn't you. Sorry to say, I am somewhat of a dilettante here. I like to think I'm pretty good at explaining things I understand, but I don't actually know a whole lot about Python—not enough to answer your question.

@Albert still not sure how you want to achieve your goal, but this might help with the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322068/determine-if-python-variable-is-an-instance-of-a-built-in-type

@Sergius: I already saw that, but it's not exactly the same question, and also none of the answers are correct for my case here.

I think the simple answer is that there's no way to determine this with any of Python's built-in introspection. How a type is implemented is implementation-dependent.

Also, note that a simple class in pure Python redefining __getattribute__ (and optionally  __setattr__) is able to provide limitless ways of storing attributes visible in ways only known to that implementation. Although that is not usually done.

Hmmm, your title says one thing - distinguish between user-class vs python-provided class.  Then the body talks about attributes.  Strictly on the user vs python aspect, a look at MyClass.__module__ (at least when MyClass is imported might be helpful.  But I get the idea you are more interested in attributes - which is fine - and maybe the title should be more explicit in that regards.

@JLPeyret My starting point was functools.partial, which is a native type. functools.partial.__module__ is not helpful here, it does not point to the actual native module (_functools) but instead just points to functools. So this does not work, at least for this example.

While playing around, I noticed that all entries in Py_tp_members will always become corresponding member descriptors in the type. And you can check for those, via inspect.ismemberdescriptor (which just checks isinstance(object, types.MemberDescriptorType)). I think this type of descriptor would not be used otherwise. So that allows to implement such a check.
Note, instead of calling this is_native_type or so, I call this type_has_native_members, to be more specific about what it actually checks (and what I want here). (But "being a native type" was anyway somewhat not well defined in the first place. I just was not sure how to properly define it.)
import inspect


def type_has_native_members(cls):
    if hasattr(cls, "__slots__"):
        return False
    for key in dir(cls):
        value = getattr(cls, key, None)
        if inspect.ismemberdescriptor(value):
            return True
    return False


# ---------------
# some tests:

import functools

assert type_has_native_members(functools.partial)

class Foo:
    pass

assert not type_has_native_members(Foo)


No, vars does not work for functools.partial, and probably other such native types.
